# Homomorphism of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

From Silverman and Tate *Rational Points on Elliptic Curves*

> It is given that 3 does not divide $p-1$, the order of the cylic group $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ . It follows that the map $x \rightarrow x^3$ is an isomorphism from $\mathbb{F}_p^*$  to itself.  . . .
>
> If 3 divides the order of the group $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ , the map $x \rightarrow x^3$ is a homomorphism to itself that is neither one-to-one or onto.

Why does this follow? I know that $\mathbb{F}_p^*$  is also a field, but I don't know if that explains why this is (or isn't, respectively) a isomorphism since they seem to be treating $\mathbb{F}_p^*$  as a group, not a field.

Comment: $\Bbb{F}_p$ is a field. $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ is just a (multiplicative) group.

Comment: $\Bbb F_p^*$ is the set of nonzero elements of $\Bbb F_p$. It's group under multiplication, not a field.

Comment: For the first claim all you need is Lagrange's theorem. $\Bbb{F}_p^*$ has no elements of order three, so the kernel of that homomorphism is trivial. Hence it is injective. Hence surjective by finiteness. In the second claim there will be elements of order three, the kernel is non-trivial etc.

Comment: Since $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is a cyclic group of order$p-1$, so corresponding each divisor of $p-1$ there exists an element of that order.